# Return templated type from container of heterogeneous templated values

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming

I am placing instances of a templated class containing heterogeneous template values into a container, such as a std::vector. When accessing a particular element from said vector, I require that the precise templated type is returned, not just the base pointer `WrapperBase*` . I've dabbled with boost::any, boost::variant, and the base class / templated child class as shown below. A compile time solution would be ideal (perhaps some meta templating magic); otherwise, a runtime RTTI-based solution would suffice.

In a perfect world, I could do something like this:

```
vector< WrapperBase > v;
v.push_back( Wrapper<int>{1} );
v.push_back( Wrapper<float>{3.14f} );
auto v = vector[0].get(); //typeid( decltype( v) ).name() would be "int"
auto v = vector[1].get(); //typeid( decltype( v) ).name() would be "float"
```

Boost variant almost provided a solution; however, I can only access the specific type within the `operator()()` method and cannot return it. The type will be consumed by further functions, so I am not able to have the visitor method perform the desired work.

This code is available http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a44681322cdbd77

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

struct WrapperBase
{
   template< typename T >
   T* get();
};

template< typename T >
struct Wrapper : WrapperBase
{
   Wrapper( T* t ) : WrapperBase(), _val( t ) {}
   T* get() { return _val; }
   T* _val;
};

template< typename T >
T* WrapperBase::get()
{
   return static_cast<Wrapper<T>>( this )->get();
}

struct Visitor : boost::static_visitor<int> //sadly, we can only return ints :(.
{
   int operator()( Wrapper<int>& b ) const
   {
      auto bType = *b.get();
      std::cout << "b type is " << typeid( decltype( bType ) ).name() << "... Val is " << bType << "...\n";
      return 2;
   }

   int operator()( Wrapper<float>& b ) const
   {
      auto bType = *b.get();
      std::cout << "b type is " << typeid( decltype( bType ) ).name() << "... Val is " << bType << "...\n";
      return 6;
   }

   int operator()( Wrapper<std::string>& b ) const
   {
      auto bType = *b.get();
      std::cout << "b type is " << typeid( decltype( bType ) ).name() << "... Val is " << bType << "...\n";
      return 12345;
   }

};

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
   std::cout << "Hello World...\n";

   int ia = 5;
   Wrapper<int> a{ &ia };

   float fb = 3.1415f;
   Wrapper<float> b{ &fb };

   std::string s = "testing this...\n";
   Wrapper<std::string> c{ &s };

   auto aType = *a.get(); //aType is "int"
   std::cout << "a type is " << typeid( decltype( aType ) ).name() << "... Val is " << aType << "...\n";

   auto bType = *b.get(); //aType is "float"
   std::cout << "b type is " << typeid( decltype( bType ) ).name() << "... Val is " << bType << "...\n";

   auto cType = *c.get(); //aType is "std::string"
   std::cout << "c type is " << typeid( decltype( cType ) ).name() << "... Val is " << cType << "...\n";

   std::vector< boost::any > vec;

   vec.push_back( &a );
   vec.push_back( &b );
   vec.push_back( &c );

   //for( int i = 0; i < vec.size() ; i++ )
   //{
   //In my actual code, I have no way of knowing I need to cast to <int> and therefore cannot cast.
   //   auto t = boost::any_cast<Wrapper<int>*>( vec[i] );
   //   std::cout << "[" << i << "] type is " << typeid( decltype( t ) ).name() << "... Val is " << t << "...\n";    
   //}    
   std::cout << "...\n...\n...\n";

   using VAR = boost::variant< Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>, Wrapper<std::string> >;

   std::vector< VAR > myVar;
   myVar.push_back( a );
   myVar.push_back( b );
   myVar.push_back( c );
   for (int i = 0; i < myVar.size() ; i++)
   {
      auto v = myVar[i];
      //apply_visitor is VERY close to what I want - I have precise type, but only within operator()()
      std::cout << boost::apply_visitor( Visitor(), v ) << "\n";
   }

   std::cout << "...\n...\n...\n";

   std::vector< WrapperBase > v;
   v.push_back( a );
   v.push_back( b );
   v.push_back( c );

   //for (int i = 0; i < v.size() ; i++)
   //{
   //   auto t = v[i].get<int>(); //same problem as boost::any, but instead I have pointer to base class
   //   std::cout << "["<<i<<"] type is " << typeid( decltype( t )).name() << "... Val is " << t << "...\n";
   //   
   //}


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `std::vector` is homogeneous by definition (even if its value type is a variant which type-erases the actual content). So you can't pry the type back out. The only heterogeneous container (or "container", as it does not meet the `Container` requirements) is `std::tuple`.

Comment: Also see https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/a-true-heterogeneous-container-in-c/, this was one of the most interesting C++ articles I have read, seems to be a little relevant, although it does not solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This brilliant article talks about how the visitor pattern can be used with type erased base objects like `std::any` https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/a-true-heterogeneous-container-in-c/, so if you use the concepts talked in there, you can in theory get to use the visitor pattern with a homogenous container.

---

Your goal of getting code like this

```
// typeid(val_one).name() is 
auto val_one = homogenous_container[runtime_value_one]; 
// typeid(val_two).name() is `double`
auto val_two = homogenous_container[runtime_value_two];
```

cannot be achieved, `auto` type deduction happens at compile time, there is no way to have it bind to a runtime condition and change the type based on that.

The closest you can come to this is to use `std::variant` and use the visitor pattern.  You cannot bind a compile time deduced type to an arbitrary runtime type.  They are just different concepts and exist at different times in the C++ compile/runtime.

Type erasure will allow you to achieve some functionality like this, but it requires that your container is composed of types that share some common interface.  For example in the case of `std::function` the types for which the type can be erased are required to be callable based on the signature of the template argument for `std::function`

Comment: I'm flattered :-). One thing I'd like to add (and should perhaps edit the post to be more explicit about) is that the performance of visiting "heterogeneous container" absolutely smashes performance of std::any (due to all the any_cast's that go on).